# Cloud Functions Firebase CLI predeploy error (typescript)

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I´m trying Cloud Functions with typescript.
After successfully installed, added a trigger and tested deploy.

**index.ts**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const createAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    const user = event.data;
    console.log('user displayname', user.displayName);
    return;
});
```

**command**

```
firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'project'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: running predeploy script.

> functions@ build D:\vmbox\project\firebase\functions
> tslint -p tslint.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc
```

**ERROR**

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**Environment**
firebase cli v3.16.0
node v6.11.2
npm v4.2.0
OS: Windows 10
terminal: powershell

///

#### Rollback to Javascript

I re-initiated functions with Javascript option, and also got errors when deploying.
I guess it may be related to a setup made by the cli for typescript.
Had to delete the "functions" option added to "firebase.json".

*option deleted in firebase.json:*

```
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix functions run build"
  }
```

Comment: [Solution moved to comment][Author of this feature] This looks like a bug on our end. We'll look at it ASAP. Though "." and "/" both work in cmd.exe I suspect that this is because cmd.exe may require an additional command to make something executable. Need to get a Windows VM to test out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just replace inside the `package.json` this

```
"build": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint.cmd -p tslint.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc.cmd"
```

on this

```
"build": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\tslint.cmd -p tslint.json && .\\node_modules\\.bin\\tsc.cmd"
```

and it will work on windows.

Comment: This is not the recommended solution because it means that your definitions now work on Windows but no other operating system. See my other answer.

Answer (score 18):

add this line to tsconfig within the functions folder:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
```

This is part of "compilerOptions" block
worked for me

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted - this fixed a bug where typescript would not find the correct types and blow the transpilation step.

Answer (score 9):

Sorry for the delay. Andrew's answer will work, but it makes the project now only work on Windows. For more information, you can check my GitHub answer [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/pull/290#issuecomment-354008701). TL;DR:

Change the scripts in your package.json to:

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc"
  }
```

Change predeploy hook in your firebase.json to:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix functions run lint && npm --prefix functions run build"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you are initializing the project and it ask you to install dependencies, you select yes, I thought I had to manually write the dependencies so i passed it but it does it for you. When I did it everything worked. I don't know if this had something to do with it but i also deleted the node modules folder and in the same folder started again from firebase init.