# React + Firebase Cloud Functions in Typescript fails to deploy

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Im my project, I would like to use

- React app in Typescript hosted on Firebase hosting
- Firestore
- Firebase functions in Typescript

I face an error when deploying. It's easy to reproduce (Now skip firestore and firebase hosting initialization)

```
yarn create react-app sample-app
cd sample-app
firebase init
(select functions by marking a box interactively)
(select typescript by marking a box interactively)
(uncomment in functions/src/index.ts)
```

functions/src/index.ts is

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

// Start writing Firebase Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Then deployment fails

```
firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'myproject'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /Users/username/sample-app/functions
> tslint --project tsconfig.json

Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> functions@ build /Users/username/sample-app/functions
> tsc

../node_modules/@types/testing-library__react/index.d.ts:13:49 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@testing-library/dom'. '/Users/username/sample-app/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/testing-library__dom` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@testing-library/dom';`

13 import { queries, Queries, BoundFunction } from '@testing-library/dom';
                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/testing-library__react/index.d.ts:16:15 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@testing-library/dom'. '/Users/username/sample-app/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/testing-library__dom` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@testing-library/dom';`

16 export * from '@testing-library/dom';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2020-08-04T06_14_06_195Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

Even after I did
`npm install @types/testing-library__dom`
in root and functions/, deployment fails.

and root directory has

```
ls
README.md     firebase.json functions     node_modules  package.json  public        src           tsconfig.json yarn.lock
```

Any idea welcome.

Comment: Can you push a reproduction of the problem to a git repository so we can debug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you try if this solution works for you?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49309428/1673761

> add this line to tsconfig within the functions folder:

```json
{                                                                                       
  "compilerOptions": { 
    ...
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
    ],
    ...
}
```

> This is part of "compilerOptions" block worked for me

Comment: Thank you so much, you save my time. Just out of curiosity, how did you find it?

Comment: You are welcome! When the types are there and they are not detected, it is usually a problem in `tsconfig.json`. It is a bit difficult to set up correctly in my opinion. Actually I cannot remember if I searched on google or if I saw the link in the related questions on the right of this page.

Comment: Thank you! I just started to write typescript a week ago now I understand better thanks to you!