# Error Firebase cli cloud function deploy. npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, typescript-eslint

I am trying to deploy a typescript cloud function to the google cloud using firebase cli. My reason for doing it like this is because I had a javascript funtions which gave me warnings about firebase environment variable being estimated. So using the firebase cli worked.

Now I have another function in typescript.

- npm: 6.14.15
- firebase: 9.19.0
- node: 14.17.6

> Here is the code.

```
"use strict";

import cbor = require("cbor");

import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import iot = require("@google-cloud/iot");
const client = new iot.v1.DeviceManagerClient();

// start cloud function
exports.configFirestorev2 = functions
    .region("europe-west1")
    .firestore
    .document("Configs/{deviceId}")
    .onWrite(async (change: functions.Change<admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot>,
        context?: functions.EventContext) => {
      if (context) {
        console.log(context.params.deviceId);
        const request = generateRequest(context.params.deviceId, change.after.data(), false);
        return client.modifyCloudToDeviceConfig(request);
      } else {
        throw (Error("no context from trigger"));
      }
    });

function generateRequest(deviceId: string, configData: any, isBinary: boolean) {
  const formattedName = client.devicePath(process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT!, functions.config().iot.core.region, functions.config().iot.core.registry, deviceId);
  let dataValue;
  if (isBinary) {
    const encoded = cbor.encode(configData);
    dataValue = encoded.toString("base64");
  } else {
    dataValue = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(configData)).toString("base64");
  }
  return {
    name: formattedName,
    binaryData: dataValue,
  };
}
```

> here is the .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "google",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: ["tsconfig.json", "tsconfig.dev.json"],
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    "/lib/**/*", // Ignore built files.
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
  ],
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
  }, 
};
```

> Here is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "@google-cloud/iot": "2.0.0",
    "@types/cbor": "^5.0.0",
    "cbor": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

when I try to deploy it using `firebase deploy --only functions`

> I get an error see the terminal log.

```
PS C:\firebase\configFirestore\functions> firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'pti-tag-copy'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix functions run lint && npm --prefix functions run build

> functions@ lint C:\firebase\configFirestore\functions
> tslint -p tslint.json

'tslint' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `tslint -p tslint.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shabir\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-06T06_44_06_259Z-debug.log
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix functions run lint && npm --prefix functions run build ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\Shabir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Shabir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Shabir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Shabir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix functions run lint && npm --prefix functions run build',
  path: 'npm --prefix functions run lint && npm --prefix functions run build',
  spawnargs: []
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

> **and here is a complete debug log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   'functions',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'lint'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.17.6
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelint', 'lint', 'postlint' ]
5 info lifecycle functions@~prelint: functions@
6 info lifecycle functions@~lint: functions@
7 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\firebase\configFirestore\functions\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Shabir\AppData\Local\cloud-code\installer\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Users\Shabir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\Shabir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\php-8.0.3-Win32-vs16-x64;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Go\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Memory and Storage Tool\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\Shabir\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Shabir\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Shabir\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ghc\tools\ghc-8.10.4\bin;C:\tools\msys64;C:\Users\Shabir\go\bin;C:\Users\Shabir\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle functions@~lint: CWD: C:\firebase\configFirestore\functions
10 silly lifecycle functions@~lint: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'tslint -p tslint.json' ]
11 silly lifecycle functions@~lint: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle functions@~lint: Failed to exec lint script
13 verbose stack Error: functions@ lint: `tslint -p tslint.json`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid functions@
15 verbose cwd C:\firebase\configFirestore
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22468
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--prefix" "functions" "run" "lint"
18 verbose node v14.17.6
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error functions@ lint: `tslint -p tslint.json`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the functions@ lint script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Could you share your package.json? It looks like you're running in a windows environment. It looks like you're having this kind of [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47777195/9330208) in which is suggeted to modify the path in the "build" script in the package.json to use the "\\" instead of "/".

Comment: I have added the package file. Please see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't managed to reproduce your issue but I was able to deploy your function in a Debian environment by following the next steps:

1. I run the following command `firebase init functions` (I picked TS and selected yes in all options)
2. `cd functions`
3. `npm install cbor`
4. `npm install @google-cloud/iot`
5. Copied your function inside the directory `functions/src/index.ts`
6. I modified the`.eslintrc.js`.
7. I run `firebase deploy --only functions`

In the `.eslintrc.js` I added the following lines in the rules section:

```
"max-len": ["error", {"code": 200}],
"require-jsdoc": 0,
```

Here is the final `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "google",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: ["tsconfig.json", "tsconfig.dev.json"],
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    "/lib/**/*", // Ignore built files.
  ],  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
  ],
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
    "max-len": ["error", {"code": 200}],
    "require-jsdoc": 0,
  },
};
```

Could you verify that you followed this steps?

### EDIT

As stated in the comments. The issue was solved by following the steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933543/parsing-error-cannot-read-file-tsconfig-json-eslint). In summary, what OP did was set `tsconfigRootDir` to `__dirname` in the `.eslintrc.js` file:

```yaml
module.exports = {
  // ...
  parserOptions: {
    project: "tsconfig.json",
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did as you described, but I still face an error

Comment: I created a new directory and did what you said. I still got errors then I found out that there is a problem with tsconfig.json path not being recognized.  And followed the steps here.-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933543/parsing-error-cannot-read-file-tsconfig-json-eslint

Comment: I understand that you solve the issue by setting tsconfigRootDir to __dirname by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64940811/9330208) right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. So in short I did first what you said, Than I got the other warning which I fixed with changing to tsconfigRootDir to __dirname.