# Error Firebase CLi, Deploy to cloud failed, error at NPM

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Im Kind of new to Android development.

I want to use Firebase Cloud to Recognize Text of non-Latin characters, to do so I'm following the [official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/recognize-text#java)

my index.js(this is the basic one and i havent changed anything)

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import vision from "@google-cloud/vision";

const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
export const annotateImage = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "unauthenticated",
      "annotateImage must be called while authenticated."
    );
  }
  try {
    return await client.annotateImage(data);
  } catch (e) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", e.message, e.details);
  }
});
```

here is the .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2020: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: "tsconfig.json",
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    sourceType: "module",

  },
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
  ],
  rules: {
    "max-len": ["error", {"code": 200}],
    "require-jsdoc": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/adjacent-overload-signatures": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/prefer-for-of": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/unified-signatures": "warn",
    "comma-dangle": "warn",
    "constructor-super": "error",
    eqeqeq: ["warn", "always"],
    "import/no-deprecated": "warn",
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "error",
    "import/no-unassigned-import": "warn",
    "no-cond-assign": "error",
    "no-duplicate-case": "error",
    "no-duplicate-imports": "error",
    "no-empty": [
      "error",
      {
        allowEmptyCatch: true,
      },
    ],
    "no-invalid-this": "error",
    "no-new-wrappers": "error",
    "no-param-reassign": "error",
    "no-redeclare": "error",
    "no-sequences": "error",
    "no-shadow": [
      "error",
      {
        hoist: "all",
      },
    ],
    "no-throw-literal": "error",
    "no-unsafe-finally": "error",
    "no-unused-labels": "error",
    "no-var": "warn",
    "no-void": "error",
    "prefer-const": "warn",
  },
  settings: {
    jsdoc: {
      tagNamePreference: {
        returns: "return",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

and this is the package.json file

```
   {
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*\"",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "compile": "npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.1",
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

when I try to deploy it using `firebase deploy --only functions` (like in the guide)
and im getting the error(this is the complete debug log)

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\genni\\DOWNLO~1\\firebase-tools-instant-win.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\snapshot\\firepit\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli',
1 verbose cli   '--script-shell=C:\\Users\\genni\\.cache\\firebase\\runtime/shell.bat',
1 verbose cli   '--globalconfig=C:\\Users\\genni\\.cache\\firebase\\runtime\\npmrc',
1 verbose cli   '--userconfig=C:\\Users\\genni\\.cache\\firebase\\runtime\\npmrc',
1 verbose cli   '--scripts-prepend-node-path=auto',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\genni\\AndroidStudioProjects\\functions-samples\\vision-annotate-images\\functions',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.18
3 info using node@v16.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle functions@~prebuild: functions@
6 info lifecycle functions@~build: functions@
7 verbose lifecycle functions@~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle functions@~build: PATH: C:\snapshot\firepit\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\genni\AndroidStudioProjects\functions-samples\vision-annotate-images\functions\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\genni\DOWNLO~1;C:\Users\genni\CACHE~1\firebase\runtime;C:\Users\genni\.cache\firebase\tools\bin;C:\Users\genni\.cache\firebase\runtime;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\genni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Users\genni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\;C:\Users\genni\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\genni\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\genni\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\genni\AppData\Local\gitkraken\bin;C:\Users\genni\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.3.1\bin;C:\Users\genni\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\genni\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle functions@~build: CWD: C:\Users\genni\AndroidStudioProjects\functions-samples\vision-annotate-images\functions
10 silly lifecycle functions@~build: Args: [ '-c', 'tsc' ]
11 silly lifecycle functions@~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle functions@~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: functions@ build: `tsc`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\firepit\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:527:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\firepit\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
14 verbose pkgid functions@
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\genni\AndroidStudioProjects\functions-samples\vision-annotate-images
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
17 verbose argv "C:\\Users\\genni\\DOWNLO~1\\firebase-tools-instant-win.exe" "C:\\snapshot\\firepit\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli" "--script-shell=C:\\Users\\genni\\.cache\\firebase\\runtime/shell.bat" "--globalconfig=C:\\Users\\genni\\.cache\\firebase\\runtime\\npmrc" "--userconfig=C:\\Users\\genni\\.cache\\firebase\\runtime\\npmrc" "--scripts-prepend-node-path=auto" "--prefix" "C:\\Users\\genni\\AndroidStudioProjects\\functions-samples\\vision-annotate-images\\functions" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v16.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.18
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error functions@ build: `tsc`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the functions@ build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

i tried to do evreything from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69461312/error-firebase-cli-cloud-function-deploy-npm-err-failed-at-the-functions-lint) and from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933543/parsing-error-cannot-read-file-tsconfig-json-eslint) but still the same eror

Comment: This has nothing to do with eslint. This has to do with `tsc` -- [TypeScript Compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#tsc-the-typescript-compiler) -- as evidenced by `Error: functions@ build: tsc`. Ensure `tsc` can complete successfully locally before attempting to deploy your function.

Comment: @anothermh how can i do that?

Comment: Run `tsc` locally

Comment: @anothermh can you help with im kinda new to this world

Comment: The command `tsc` is the TypeScript Compiler. It's what you run to transpile TypeScript into pure JavaScript. The error message you're seeing is saying that for some reason the command `tsc` failed. You should open a command prompt to your functions folder and run `tsc` or `npm tsc` and observe the output to look for errors.

Comment: @anothermh okay i installed tsc accroding to this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/download) but still have the same problem

Comment: Post package.json and explain *exactly* what your process is for building the function and deploying it.

Comment: @anothermh already post package.json file and what I want to do is what i wrote "I want to use Firebase Cloud to Recognize Text of non-Latin characters, to do so I'm following the"

Comment: You did not post package.json, you posted your eslint config twice. Please post package.json.

Comment: @anothermh yes sorry. fixed now

Comment: You shouldn't need to install anything extra. Simply run `npx tsc` and [edit] your question with the result of running that command